# Aligning multiple Divisions within a Division

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align multiple DIVs horizontally and vertically inside my main DIV `divBig`. Each DIV should overlap one over the other but should be in the centre of the main DIV `divBig`.

This is my DIV structure:

```
<div id="divBig">
   <div class="divBigInner">
     <img class="innerSub1" src="image.png" />
     <div class="innerSub2"></div>
     <div class="innerSub3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried so far. But Does not align correctly.

```
#divBig {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    text-align: center;
}
.divBigInner{
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.innerSub1{
    position:absolute;
    max-width:550px;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.innerSub2{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:10px;
    display:inline;
}
.innerSub3{
    position:relative;
    max-width:550px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what the output you are looking for?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv: All DIVs should be centred. If I put text or an image in each DIV they all chould be aligned horizontally and vertically inside `divBig`

Answer (score 0):

like this you are asking?

```
<div id="divBig">
   <div class="divBigInner" align="center">
     <div class="innerSub1"></div>
     <div class="innerSub2"></div>
     <div class="innerSub3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
<style>
#divBig {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.divBigInner{
    height: 100%;
}
.innerSub1,.innerSub2,.innerSub3{
    border:1px solid #f00;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    width:100px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Can you try this:

            <div id="divBig">
               <div class="divBigInner" align="center">
                 <div class="innerSub1"></div>
                 <div class="innerSub2"></div>
                 <div class="innerSub3"></div>
               </div>
            </div>

        Css

            <style>
            #divBig {
                background-color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .divBigInner{
                height: 100%;
position:relative;
            }
            .innerSub1,.innerSub2,.innerSub3{
                border:1px solid #f00;
                padding:10px;
                margin:10px;
                width:100px;
    height:100px;
                position:absolute;
                margin-left:-50px; /*formula to make div center horizontal (left 50% - width/2)*/
        margin-top:-50px; /*formula to make div center vertical (top 50% - height/2)*/
            }

            </style>
```